# Get last part of url with / at the end

Tags: javascript, string, url

I'm trying to get the last part of this url:

```
http://webserver/Foo/login/
```

the code that I wrote:

```
var location = window.location.href.split('/').pop();
```

will return an empty string 'cause after the `/` there is nothing.
I need to get at least the previous part, so in this case, login.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `.pop().pop()`

But ideally don't parse a string with a `/` at the end.

Comment: ^ Didn't realize Magnitude was on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jack You can't chain `.pop()`, the first one return a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `String.replace()`(used to replace possible `/` at the end of the string) and `String.split()` functions:

```js
var url = 'http://webserver/Foo/login/',
    last_section = url.replace(/\/+$/, '').split('/').pop();
    
console.log(last_section);
```

Comment: this will working for malformatted url such as login///// ?

Comment: @AgainMe, with my last edit (`/\/+$/`) - yes, it will work. Try and you'll see

Comment: that's really nice solution

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
location.pathname.match(/[^/]*(?=\/*$)/)[0]
```

**Explanation:**

- [`Location.pathname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname) is a string containing an initial `'/'` followed by the [path of the URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax).
- [`String.prototype.match(regexp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array of the matches.
- `[^/]*` matches [anything but a slash](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), and that [zero or more times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).
- `(?=\/*$)` matches a slash zero or more times [at the end of the string](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), [while not including it](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead).
- There is always exactly one match, so we retrieve it with `[0]`.

**Example:**

For all these URLs the output is `login`:

- `http://webserver/Foo/login`
- `http://webserver/Foo/login/`
- `http://webserver/Foo/login//`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getLastPartURL = url => {
  const parts = url.split('/');
  const length = parts.length;
  return parts[length - 1] == '' ? parts[length - 2] : parts[length - 1]
}

console.log(getLastPartURL('http://webserver/Foo/login/'))
console.log(getLastPartURL('http://webserver/Foo/login'))
console.log(getLastPartURL('http://webserver/Foo/'))
console.log(getLastPartURL('http://webserver/Foo'))
```